# Using custom auth through hardware device on Windows network map drive possible?

Tags: windows, network-share, cifs, windows-authentication

I want to custom the auth method when connecting smb as a client on Windows to a linux server.

I expect to it to work like this: When connecting as a network map drive, Windows auth center will read from  a specified hardware interface(eg. a com port) to get the username + password and send to the server. So there's no need to manually input username+password through keyboard. I just want to know is it possible on windows? If it is, how to configure or program the Windows auth componet? (let's say for example on  win10)

Comment: I haven't seen such application in public and you cannot configure it for sure with default Windows 10 tools. I think a custom agent (driver?) should be developed, which monitors requests to share and authenticate with stored (on device/file/etc) credential.

Answer (score 0):

After searching and trying some other complicate method. I finally came up with a very simple idea that works for myself: Just use the `net` command. The `net * \\ip\sharepath /user:username password`  will silently map net drive. So I can create a program and read the auth key from some specific device and execute this command to mount the cifs share.